# Can't restore iPad 2 with new iTunes... error 9

Tags: ios, itunes

Ok so I updated my iTunes on my (Mac Book Pro) and tried to install the new iOS on my iPad... got error 9.  (((Switched cables, tried the other usb connecter... same error.)))  Searched the net... everything kept saying usb issues or firewall(I don't have one).  Thought maybe an issue with that computer.

So I then tried my (mac mini) that had an older iTunes and re-installed iOS 4.2 on my iPad.  It worked!!!!

So I updated iTunes on the mac mini and tried to install iOS on my iPad... error 9...  Now both my computers have the new iTunes and am stuck with the iPad waiting to be restored.

What is with this new iTunes/new iOS ????

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
Status Displayed using iTunes of the restore...
- Extracting software(iPad Recovering Mode:  iTunes is preparing to restore the software on this iPad)
- Preparing iPad for Restore
- Waiting for iPad  (iPad screen now shows a "big apple" on it as apposed to a USB cable pointing to iTunes)
- Verifying iPad restore with Apple
- Waiting for iPad
- The iPad could not be restored.  An unknown error occurred (9).
- also  (the "big apple" on iPad screen switch to a "small apple" and then the "iTunes and usb" image showed up)
```

Comment: According to the [Apple KB](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204770) error 9 looks like a network connectivity fail

Comment: Had done that.  Switched cables.  Switch Usb ports.  Switched computers.  Only the older iTunes worked.

Comment: None of that would affect, for instance, your router. The test would be over a different network.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had the same issue as well.

After a lot of searching I found an answer on one of the Apple Discussion Threads.
Try installing [Wondershare Dr.Fone for iOS](http://www.wondershare.com/drfone-iphone-data-recovery.html) and follow the instructions on the screen.

At the least it should recover the data on your device and let you use it as it was in it's earlier state.

I'm yet to find out how to **update** my iPad 2 through iTunes without the silly error 9.
I'll edit my answer when I do so.

Comment: I downloaded and older version of iTunes from the apple site and was able to get the iPad up and working... all data is still there too.  But can't get the iOS to update.  Talked with Apple and also when to an Apple store to get one of the "geniuses" to try... and failed to update as well.  Was told for $250 I could purchase another iPad 2 on return of this one.

Comment: It seems like with the latest iOS version I was able to install it via iTunes without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely try Wondershare Dr. Fone for iOS. I used the trial version and it fixed this problem immediately! I have an Apple store in my city and just got back from the "Genius Bar" appointment wherein I was told that my iPad 2 suffered a hardware failure during the iOS update, was not recoverable and thus, completely dead. Dr. Fone to the rescue!!!